# Nginx not running

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, centos8

I am using AWS EC2 centos 8 and I cannot get nginx to run. I believe I am having an issue with my configuration files setup.

I get the following error when I try to run nginx:
**nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)**

I've tested the config files using the `sudo nginx -t` command and I get
`nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`

I added a sites-enabled directory with my app folder name in my environment. My nginx did not come with a /sites-enabled directory.

I've tried many variations of these two files and without the /sites-enabled directory. Here is what I think is my best shot at getting it to work:

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;
 
    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/dmrApp:

```
server  {
    listen 80;
    server_name 3.88.229.253;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location /static{
        alias /home/ec2-user/environments/DMRapp3/dmrApp/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    }
```

I was following a tutorial that asked to use "include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;" in location of my dmrApp file but proxy_params never came with my nginx installation. I found a site that suggested adding all the "proxy_set_header" lines.

I know my issue is similar to many because I’ve spent hours researching. Many have given me optimism for a resolution but to no success.

Comment: you should be doing something like `sudo service nginx start`

Comment: so i would ask how are you starting it and what are the permissions on `/etc/nginx/` and `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

Comment: the ```sudo service nginx start``` returns a "failed because the control process exited with error code”. When I check error code in systemctl status nginx.service, the error code is same as above.
I did a ```ls -ltr /etc/nginx/``` root is listed near most of the files within the directory, except two. My user is next to sites-enabled and nginx.conf. nginx.conf has “-rw-rw-r--. 1 ec2-user ec2-user 2478 Dec  6 19:47 nginx.conf”

Comment: the permissions i use for nginx is for files in /etc/nginx i have 664 and myuser as user and sudo as group, and for folders i have chmod g+rxws so 775 and myuser and sudo.